# Reason for TCP Slow Start in Subsequent Connections

Tags: tcp

From my understanding TCP slow start is used to compensate and prevent congestion and loss. When a connection is successfully established and used for a while, the bandwidth of the TCP connection is about as large as possible. 
Everytime a new connection is established, even if they are concurrent, TCP slow start is used, starting the connection with a low window size, even though both TCP stacks already know the behaviour of the physical layer.

Why do TCP stacks always perform a slow start even though they could have remembered the window size of recent former connections to the same partner? Couldn't they safely do an appropriate faster start and degrade the connection afterwards if the link conditions change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe to assume that two TCP connections, even between the same two endpoints, will take the same route. It is not unusual, for example, to have load balancing across multiple connections that takes into account the ports involved.

This may seem an odd choice, but it makes sense because TCP performance can suffer if a lot of packets are received out of order and gluing a connection to a route avoids this. Often the source IP, destination IP, protocol, source port (if applicable) and destination port (if applicable) are hashed and the hash is used to select the next hop.

Comment: If it's like that, you also could not rely on IPv6 Path MTU Discovery, do you?

Comment: @MaxRied Why do you say that? Strictly speaking, there's no guarantee two successive packets will ever take the same path, but networking engineers know that MTU detection is done and they try to keep paths "sticky" to keep performance reasonable.